# smoke domain casts shadow

Tags: smoke-simulation

I messing around with a scene where smoke blasts into a room from a tube in the wall.

The scene works out fine. I have set the domain to adaptive domain.

The only problem i have now is that the adaptive domain casts shadow on the room.

I have added a screenshot of the scene and a screenshot of the node setup for the domain.

Any clues on how to avoid that ?

[image: scene]

[image: nodesetup]

blend file

[image]]

Comment: Based on pictures I'm guessing that the non-smoke areas still have some density, and that could probably be fixed by clipping the low density areas. I cannot, however test that without a file. could you please upload one here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: ofc and thx alot, i have uploaded the file here

[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2132" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2132/)

Comment: Finished the test, didn't appear to fix it :/

Comment: oh well thx for trying anyways.. hope someone else has an idea how to fix that shadow

Comment: solution for now is to make the domain the same size as the room.. its not perfekt and baking takes forever, but i cant figure out how to solve the shadow casting from the adaptive domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select your domain, under properties panel go to object--> cycles settings--> deactivate shadow [image: deactivate_cycles_shadow]

Comment: ohh i will give that a try thx alot :-)

Comment: At least, I've tried with your data and it seemed to work

Answer (score 2):

I know it´s quite a while since this Thread was active, but I had the same problem and no of all the solutions (and I searched a lot of other threads..) solved my problem.
My Problem was.. the Render Settings!

Increase your "Light Path"-Settings, and it works.
I hope I could help somebody, too.

[image: Old Settings]

[image: New Settings]

[image: Viewport]

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this do?  Vanilla 'OpenGL' render, using smoke images on multiple planes which can be coloured, scaled and slid out from the pipe to suit.

[image]

It only takes about 6 secs to render. (10 secs at full size) I d/loaded your file but as you mentioned, it takes an age to render in cycles,

Comment: thx for the suggestention , but no it has to be a real raytrace to get it more photorealistic as i am going to use it in a composite with a model (a real human model that is)